# What does "for" mean exactly in this context?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

> She clapped *for* silence.

Is it:

1. having the purpose of (She clapped for the purpose of silence.)
2. showing meaning (She clapped, which shows the meaning of silence.)
3. in order to get or achieve (She clapped in order to get silence.)

Comment: It's (3) (fairly obviously, I would have thought).

Comment: Same meaning as "we all scream for ice cream." So, a different usage than "they clapped for the hero," or "she clapped for emphasis." And, if the follow-up question is "how would you know which use applies," the answer as always is "context"—the rest of those clauses explain to us about getting something, benefitting someone, or getting something.